# How to share a folder with one person with cmd

Tags: windows, permissions, cmd, sharing

i need to make the users program on X computer only accessible to "admin" using a batch file . the net comand seems to have only a delete option for perms using net share, but i need to  only admin and the local machine can access it. i think net may not work but i dont even know.
Currently, the perms are:

EVERYONE: Full

LOCAL MACHINE: full

i need to delete the entry everyone, and add the entry admin. would i use `net share /delete`?

Comment: Are you trying to change the permissions on a share or on a file or directory?  The `icacls` command changes permissions for files and directories.

Comment: it originaly was the icals comand but i changed the title yesterday. i originaly tried icals but it did exactly as you stated, and it did pointless things. i am trying to use net share to do this

Comment: The `net share` command allows you to control whether particular directories on the computer are available to people on other computers.  Is this what you want to do?  Or do you want to control whether a particular directory or file is available to people on the *same* computer?

Comment: No its for other computers. what i plan to do is make a bat file and put it in startup on a computer and that batch file patches the bug that lets people access other peoples files. this is to be done without them knowing we had such a fatal bug.

Comment: The `net share` command doesn't appear to have an option for changing permissions on an existing share, but you could always delete the share and recreate it - although I'm unclear on why the share was necessary in the first place, since administrators can always get in using the `C$` share instead.

Comment: Ok, so i tried using "net share Users \\%computername% /delete", but it says: "Users have open files on Users.  Continuing the operation will force the files closed." does that mean it will log the user out? also can i bypass that prompt?

Comment: It won't log out the user who is actually sitting in front of the computer in question, if that's what you mean.  But if people are actually using the share, are you sure you want to delete it?  Do you know why the share was created in the first place?

Comment: You can probably bypass the prompt with something like `echo y | net share Users /delete` but it would be preferable to work out who has the files open and close them properly.  Forcing the files closed could result in them becoming corrupted.  Keep in mind that the folders in Users normally have permissions that only let the right people in (note that the share permissions do not override this) so if this is messed up it should probably be fixed anyway.  Removing the share only affects remote access, the person logged into the computer will still have access to everyone else's files.